# How to use custom database entries in genealogytree package

Tags: genealogytree

I would like to know how to handle custom data in my genealogytree database.

For the first step I added the new key to the database entries:

```
p{
  birth- = {1872-10-11},
  death- = {1948-05-14},
  deathage = {75},
}
```

In the options I set `/gtr/database unknown key=save` according to p. 157 of the manual which should put the data to `/gtr/database/save/deathage`.

Now I am wondering how to access those data. How can I check if they custom key is set (`\gtrif…`?) and how can I print the content in a custom `database format`?

**Edit**: Testing with a minimal example makes me believe that my custom data are not available at `\grtDBdeathage` like other pieces of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unknown keys can be saved, but there is no special package support to automatically create macros like `\grtDBdeathage`.

You can access private keys like `/gtr/database/save/deathage` as documented in the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) **'82 Key Management'**, e.g.

```
\pgfkeysvalueof{/gtr/database/save/deathage}
```

or

```
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/save/deathage/.get=\mymacro}
\mymacro
```

or

```
\gtrset{database/save/deathage/.get=\mymacro}
\mymacro
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to the right place!

I ended up defining a new database format derived from `full` and added this part:

`\pgfkeysifdefined{/gtr/database/save/deathage}{ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/gtr/database/save/deathage})}{}`